# Threads in python facing trouble

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written very basic python code for threading...

```
import time
import thread

def print_hello(name,delay):
    while 1:
        print name
        time.sleep(delay)

        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(print_hello, ("frist",1,))
            thread.start_new_thread(print_hello, ("second",2,))
        except:
            print "unable to start thread"

        time.sleep(4)
        print "hello"
```

which output is:

```
second
frist
frist
second
frist
frist
hello
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
  sys.excepthook is missing
  lost sys.stderr

Unhandled exception in thread started by 
  sys.excepthook is missing
  lost sys.stderr
```

my query is:

1. why second coming 1st?
2. why the exception?

Comment: Some people, when faced with a problem, think "I'll use threads". Then two they hav erpoblesms.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: Because threading is tricksy.

Zero-th of all, the code entered above can't possibly produce the output you show. I think what you really intended was for everything from the `try:` down to be out-dented to the same level as `def`. When I make that change, and run your code I get results similar to yours, *sometimes*.

To address your frist question: Frist comes second because `time.sleep()` does not guarantee that it will delay for exactly the specified time. See the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).
When I run your code, sometimes frist comes second and sometimes frist comes first, and sometimes they show up together.

To address your second question: Because your two background threads get the rug pulled out from under them when the main program exits.

The two threads run ok while the main program executes the `sleep` and `print`. Once those complete, the program tries to exit. At about the same time, the two threads are trying to print their output.

I found that if you increase the `sleep(4)` to `sleep(5.5)` it runs a lot cleaner because neither thread is trying to `print` while the program is exiting.

In real life what you should do is have a mechanism to signal the background threads to break out of their infinte loop and exit before the main program exits, then have the main program wait (by calling `join()`) until the threads have stopped before exiting.

Read up about [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join).

Comment: Hello,I am new in threding programs.I got the point here,but i also have some basic query how does thread actually work? is it that all thred is allocated to a seperate stack,i am surprise why thread stops once program execution stops.

Comment: @user2743375 I don't know a lot about the internal details. Perhaps this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340/how-do-threads-work-in-python-and-what-are-common-python-threading-specific-pit) will help.

Comment: +1 for consistent use of "frist" :D

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop.

The `print_hello` function starts a thread which starts a thread which starts a thread...

Bad things will happen and eventually it will crash.