# Is "Python only run one thread in parallel" true?

Tags: python

Got this question during an interview.

I was talking about two threads modifying one same dictionary which causes wrong data.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340/how-do-threads-work-in-python-and-what-are-common-python-threading-specific-pit).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).