# Do I use a whole processor thread when I start a thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I just discovered a module called threading in Python, and it opened a whole world of doors for me. I'm able to do a lot of things I couldn't do before.
But now that I think about it am I limited by my processor threads? I'm using an i7-8700k (6 Cores, 12 Threads) Like every time a start threading a function with Thread(target=func).start() am I using 1 whole "physical" thread? I'd be a little scared to run a program that uses more than the available threads. Will it be a problem?

Comment: FYI: Some people say "hardware thread" or "processor thread" when they're talking about hyper-threaded processors, but that's not what "thread" means when you say it all by itself. A thread is not a physical thing. A thread is a _virtual_ agent who executes your code. The same hardware that powers your virtual agent potentially can divide its time between your thread and threads in other programs.

Comment: yeah thats why i putted physical between "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not using a full thread don't worry about that.

You could check this SO topic for more info: [How do threads work in Python, and what are common Python-threading specific pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340/how-do-threads-work-in-python-and-what-are-common-python-threading-specific-pit)

Another library that might interest you is asyncio: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html